# Merge dataframes inside a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, group-by, nested

I have a dictionary `dict` of dataframes such as:

```
{   
‘table_1’:              name             color             type
                        Banana           Yellow            Fruit,
‘another_table_1’:      city             state             country
                        Atlanta          Georgia           United States,
‘and_another_table_1’:  firstname        middlename        lastname
                        John             Patrick           Snow,
‘table_2’:              name             color             type
                        Red              Apple             Fruit,
‘another_table_2’:      city             state             country
                        Arlington        Virginia          United States,
‘and_another_table_2’:  firstname        middlename        lastname
                        Alex             Justin            Brown,
‘table_3’:              name             color             type
                        Lettuce          Green             Vegetable,
‘another_table_3’:      city             state             country
                        Dallas           Texas             United States,
‘and_another_table_3’:  firstname        middlename        lastname
                        Michael          Alex              Smith             }
```

I would like to merge these dataframes together based on their names so that in the end I will have only 3 dataframes:

`table`

```
name        color       type
Banana     Yellow     Fruit
Red         Apple     Fruit
Lettuce     Green     Vegetable
```

`another_table`

```
city        state          country
Atlanta     Georgia        United States
Arlington   Virginia       United States
Dallas      Texas          United States
```

`and_another_table`

```
firstname        middlename        lastname
John             Patrick           Snow
Alex             Justin            Brown
Michael          Alex              Smith
```

Based on my initial research it seems like this should be possible with Python:

1. By using `.split`, dictionary comprehension and `itertools.groupby` to group together dataframes inside the dictionary based on key names
2. Creating dictionary of dictionaries with these grouped results
3. Using `pandas.concat` function to loop through these dictionaries and group dataframes together

I don't have a lot of experience with Python and I am a bit lost on how to actually code this.

I have reviewed
[How to group similar items in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659153/how-to-group-similar-items-in-a-list) and
[Merge dataframes in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233982/merge-dataframes-in-a-dictionary) posts but they were not as helpful because in my case name length of dataframes varies.

Also I do not want to hardcode any dataframe names, because there are more than a 1000 of them.

Comment: Do the dict keys have a naming convention that makes it obvious which final table they will belong to, like in the example, where you can use everything before the final `'_'`?

Comment: Dict keys have common names except the last digit "_1" or "_2". So "table_1", "table_2" and "table_3" will have common name "table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

Give this dictionary of dataframes:

```
dd = {'table_1': pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Banana'], 'color':['Yellow'], 'type':'Fruit'}),
      'table_2': pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Apple'], 'color':['Red'], 'type':'Fruit'}),
      'another_table_1':pd.DataFrame({'city':['Atlanta'],'state':['Georgia'], 'Country':['United States']}),
      'another_table_2':pd.DataFrame({'city':['Arlinton'],'state':['Virginia'], 'Country':['United States']}),
      'and_another_table_1':pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['John'], 'middlename':['Patrick'], 'lastnme':['Snow']}),
      'and_another_table_2':pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['Alex'], 'middlename':['Justin'], 'lastnme':['Brown']}),
     }

tables = set([i.rsplit('_', 1)[0] for i in dd.keys()])
dict_of_dfs = {i:pd.concat([dd[x] for x in dd.keys() if x.startswith(i)]) for i in tables}
```

Outputs a new dictionary of combined tables:

```
dict_of_dfs['table']

#      Name   color   type
# 0  Banana  Yellow  Fruit
# 0   Apple     Red  Fruit

dict_of_dfs['another_table']

#        city     state        Country
# 0   Atlanta   Georgia  United States
# 0  Arlinton  Virginia  United States

dict_of_dfs['and_another_table']

#   firstname middlename lastnme
# 0      John    Patrick    Snow
# 0      Alex     Justin   Brown
```

Another way using defaultdict from collections, create a list of combined dataframes:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

dd = {'table_1': pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Banana'], 'color':['Yellow'], 'type':'Fruit'}),
      'table_2': pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Apple'], 'color':['Red'], 'type':'Fruit'}),
      'another_table_1':pd.DataFrame({'city':['Atlanta'],'state':['Georgia'], 'Country':['United States']}),
      'another_table_2':pd.DataFrame({'city':['Arlinton'],'state':['Virginia'], 'Country':['United States']}),
      'and_another_table_1':pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['John'], 'middlename':['Patrick'], 'lastnme':['Snow']}),
      'and_another_table_2':pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['Alex'], 'middlename':['Justin'], 'lastnme':['Brown']}),
     }
tables = set([i.rsplit('_', 1)[0] for i in dd.keys()])

d = defaultdict(list)

[d[i].append(dd[k]) for i in tables for k in dd.keys() if k.startswith(i)]
l_of_dfs = [pd.concat(d[i]) for i in d.keys()]
print(l_of_dfs[0])
print('\n')
print(l_of_dfs[1])
print('\n')
print(l_of_dfs[2])
```

Output:

```
       city     state        Country
0   Atlanta   Georgia  United States
0  Arlinton  Virginia  United States


  firstname middlename lastnme
0      John    Patrick    Snow
0      Alex     Justin   Brown


     Name   color   type
0  Banana  Yellow  Fruit
0   Apple     Red  Fruit
```