# Save dictionary to Pandas dataframe with keys as columns and merge indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, key

I know there are already lots of posts on how to convert a pandas dict to a dataframe, however I could not find one discussing the issue I have.
My dictionary looks as follows:

```
[Out 23]:
{'atmosphere':       0
 2     5
 9     4
 15    1
 26    5
 29    5
 ...  ..
 2621  4
 6419  3
 
 [6934 rows x 1 columns],
 'communication':       0
 13    1
 15    1
 26    1
 2621  2
 3119  5
 ...  ..
 6419  4
 6532  1
 
 [714 rows x 1 columns]
```

Now, what I want is to create a dataframe out of this dictionary, where the 'atmosphere' and 'communication' are the columns, and the indices of both items are merged, so that the dataframe looks as follows:

```
index    atmosphere    commmunication
2           5
9           4
13                           1
15          1                1
26          5                1
29          5
2621        4                2
3119                         5
6419        3                4
6532                         1
```

I already tried pd.DataFrame.from_dict, but it saves all values in one row.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: + eventually `sort_index` and `reset_index`

Comment: @jezrael feel free to update

Comment: @jezrael: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233982/merge-dataframes-in-a-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) for remove second level `0` from `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
d = {'atmosphere':pd.DataFrame({0: {2: 5, 9: 4, 15: 1, 26: 5, 29: 5, 
                                    2621: 4, 6419: 3}}),
     'communication':pd.DataFrame({0: {13: 1, 15: 1, 26: 1, 2621: 2,
                                       3119: 5, 6419: 4, 6532: 1}})}

print (d['atmosphere'])
      0
2     5
9     4
15    1
26    5
29    5
2621  4
6419  3

print (d['communication'])
      0
13    1
15    1
26    1
2621  2
3119  5
6419  4
6532  1
```

---

```
df = pd.concat(d, axis=1).droplevel(1, axis=1)
print (df)
      atmosphere  communication
2            5.0            NaN
9            4.0            NaN
13           NaN            1.0
15           1.0            1.0
26           5.0            1.0
29           5.0            NaN
2621         4.0            2.0
3119         NaN            5.0
6419         3.0            4.0
6532         NaN            1.0
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = pd.concat({k: v[0] for k, v in d.items()}, axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried but I receive "TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"

Comment: @Freyana - in question is dictionary `{'atmosphere':       0
 2     5...`, in your real data it is different?

Comment: in my real data I have 10 more keys apart from atmosphere and communication, but the content is of the same type (Index value & integer)

Comment: @Freyana - I add sample data, can you check if your are different?

Comment: my output looks exactly the same ... But as I'm a beginner I don't know whether I might get sth wrong so in case you have time I uploaded my py-file and the data I'm using to this folder: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Arkw7Y7i28Jikyvvs4Z9Ec5rdccR?e=atqNEg

Comment: @Freyana -  what is ouput of `print(dct['Vorgesetztenverhalten'])` ?

Comment: [      0
75    3
90    3
958   3
1133  1
1235  1
...  ..
4530  1
4531  1
4532  4
4533  1
4534  1

[3935 rows x 1 columns]]

Comment: same style as the output of the other keys

Comment: @Freyana - so `print (type((dct['Vorgesetztenverhalten'])))`  is list?

Comment: @Freyana - seems used`dct = {k:[v] for k,v in dct.items()}` ?

Comment: Yes it says: <class 'list'>

Comment: @Freyana - and `print (len((dct['Vorgesetztenverhalten'])))` ?

Comment: Omg, yes, absolutely my mistake!!! Forgot that I ran the above code and changed dct because I tried another solution first. Now it works!! Thank you so much for your time and sorry for my sloppiness!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on the values and [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) with the dictionary keys:

```
out = pd.concat(d.values(), axis=1).set_axis(d, axis=1)
```

output:

```
      atmosphere  communication
2            5.0            NaN
9            4.0            NaN
13           NaN            1.0
15           1.0            1.0
26           5.0            1.0
29           5.0            NaN
2621         4.0            2.0
3119         NaN            5.0
6419         3.0            4.0
6532         NaN            1.0
```