# Concatening Dataframes in Dictionary Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, concatenation

Hoping someone knowledgeable with pandas might be able to steer me in the right direction. I have a dictionary that contains a number of time series data frames for its values. The data frames look like this for each month, respectively:

[image]

I am trying to get an output like this:

[image]

I attempted  a concatenation with the following code:

```
header = next(iter(dict.values())).iloc[0]
for v in dict.values():
    out=pd.concat([v[1:]],axis=0,ignore_index=True)
out.columns=header
print(out)
```

Unfortunately, my end result is not the full concatenation. Rather, I just get something like this:

[image]

I'm missing my header, and I seem to be only getting the last values in the dictionary concatenated to the result. Is pd.concat a good method to use? Or should I instead use append or merge?

Any guidance would be very much appreciated here, thanks.

Comment: post a testable dict of dataframes

Comment: sorry, to clarify: did you want to see the contents of the initial dictionary object?

Comment: instead of images you need to post a testable and reproducible fragment of your dict of dataframes

Comment: To make it clear, Roman means this: share [code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). This is part of providing [mre].

Comment: Also it looks like you have overwritten the [python function `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) as a variable name for a dictionary. Good practices are to refrain from doing that. Possible conflicts later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge dataframes in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233982/merge-dataframes-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: @OCa, unfortunately not. If i try that method, I get get the invalidindexerror: "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects."

Comment: Oh but that's interesting. Your post would gain if you added that attempt and that information. But see, that's why we really need you to post text constructors of your input data.

Comment: @Oca, the input data is pretty wild. I used Py32 to comb through my inbox, grab zip files that were emailed, and unpacked the tabular documents from the zip files to a dictionary where the key was the file name and date, and the values were the tabular data. I'll see if I can add more later to this post. Thanks for the engagement

Comment: all right, anything small yet representative will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be overthinking this. `pd.concat` is the correct tool but one of the reasons for that is you don't need to iterate through your dict.

```
#set up fake data
data = {'September': pd.DataFrame({'ReportingDate': ['9/30/2023', '9/30/2023', '9/30/2023'],
                                   'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                                   'Volume': [1, 2, 3]}),
        'October': pd.DataFrame({'ReportingDate': ['10/31/2023', '10/31/2023', '10/31/2023'],
                                 'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                                 'Volume': [1, 2, 3]})
        }

df = pd.concat(data.values(), ignore_index = True)
print(df)
```

and that gives

```
  ReportingDate Category  Volume
0     9/30/2023        A       1
1     9/30/2023        B       2
2     9/30/2023        C       3
3    10/31/2023        A       1
4    10/31/2023        B       2
5    10/31/2023        C       3
```

If you give `pd.concat` a list of dataframes and `axis = 0` (which I omitted just because it's the default), it will connect them end-to-end, aligning the columns according to their label. `data.values()` is not technically a list (it's a `dict_values` object) but it's close enough to behave like one in this context.

Edit: to give some further context to why you're seeing the results are with your first attempt. In your iteration you are rewriting the variable `out` each time, so your end result is only what you overwrote it with in the last iteration. In your first line where you define `header`, you are extracting the first row of your first dataframe, but pandas knows that your column labels aren't rows. So the reason your end result looks like it doesn't have column labels is that your column labels are the values from the first row of your first dataframe.